# JavaScript FileReader is duplicating the onload callback

Tags: javascript

The following code is driving me nuts. It picks up when a file upload input has changed and then grabs the image via FileReader. The annoying thing is, and i can't work out why, that is keeps incrementally duplicating the onload event. So the first time i select a file it fires onload once, if i select a second file with the same file input the onload fires twice, if i select a file again it fires 3 times and on like that.

```
var ele = document.getElementById('photo-upload');
        ele.addEventListener('change',function(e){

            console.log("FLE CHANGED");

            var file = e.target.files[0];
            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = function(e){
                console.log("FILE READER LOADED");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Share complete code, Your HTML too

Comment: Create [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) if possible.

Comment: The code is way too long to share it all, it's part of a much larger project. the answer is below to it, but then when using readAsDataURL it says the object is in an invalid state

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating new file reader with each click on `<input type="file" id="photo-upload" />`.

I've modified your code:

```
const ele = document.getElementById('photo-upload');
const fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function(e){
  console.log("FILE READER LOADED");
}
ele.addEventListener('change',function(e){
  console.log("FLE CHANGED");
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  // load file with using on of fr methods
  // eg.
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

Working example:

```js
const ele = document.getElementById('photo-upload');
const fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = evt => {
  console.log(evt.target);
  console.log("FILE READER LOADED");
}
ele.addEventListener('change', evt => {
  console.log("FLE CHANGED");
  const file = evt.target.files[0];
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
})
```

```html
<input type="file" id="photo-upload" />
```

Comment: I get what you're saying here, but when i wrote that i kinda assumed creating a NEW object would literally be that, not firing the evet on all the previous objects. I'll give this a try..

Comment: Saying that, it's not quite right. Now in the console i get "The object is in an invalid state" on every single upload. That's when using readAsDataURL() for pulling in images as data string.

Comment: I've edited the anwser and added working code snippet

Comment: What have you changed? You're not using readAsDataURL which is what i need..  Anyway with adding the code how you have done it i still get: InvalidStateError: The object is in an invalid state. readAsDataURL - after the first image is selected and start trying a 2nd or 3rd

Comment: I've changed html part - `button` to `input`
As I stated in anwser you may use different FileReader [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Methods). 

In snippet I've used [Arrow Function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: I am going to accept your answer, but do you have any idea why i keep getting the invalid state error in the console? It doesn't stop the image data working but it just keeps adding more and more errors to the console on every file selection

Comment: If you put error generating code eg. here https://jsfiddle.net/ I would check that out and try to reproduce the error.

Comment: That's odd, i added very similar code to the jsfiddle and the error doesn't happen in the console.In fact the code isn't much different from what i'm using elsewhere. https://jsfiddle.net/xo9w7p3r/4/ - the console just doesn't show the errors i'm getting, how strange.

Comment: Hmm, strange indeed. If I'll come up with something I will let you know.